# How to use a cell value as a sheet name in Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to create a script that copies rows from one sheet to another. The core of this is something I've done before using GetSheetByName() to name the source and target sheets, but for this particular project there are a lot of target sheets, so I need the target sheet names to be variable and based on a String that will be in the final cell of each row.

To complicate matters, that final cell will be using a VLOOKUP formula to get the relevant sheet name based on the data in the row.

I know I've been able to use cell references as a sheet reference in a formula natively in Google Sheets using the INDIRECT function, but I haven't found an equivalent for Google Apps Script.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: What's the problem? What have you tried? Where is it failing? It would help if you posted code.

Comment: Feel free to accept the answer below if you feel it was useful to you

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**

Assuming that the last cell of each row is in the same column and you want to get the last cell of every row, you could use `getRange(rage).getValue()` to get all the data within the specified range or `getDataRange().getValue()` to get all the data within a Sheet. Both will return an array which you can loop through to access the data.

**Sample Code:**

```js
function getRowLastCell(){
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var data=sheet.getDataRange().getValues(); //get all data from Sheet1
  var array = new Array();
  for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    for(var j = 0; j < data[i].length; j++) {
      if(j == data[i].length-1){ //check the last cell for each row.
        array.push(data[i][j]); //save to array
      }
    }              
  }
}
```

In my example, I looped through the array and added condition that will check the last element of each row then save the content to an array.

From there, you can loop through the newly populated array and access each element to do operations.

### Reference

[GetDataRange()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getdatarange)

[GetRange()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow,-column)

Comment: I don't think the OP wants to rename the sheets. He just want to get the last cell in every row which contains the name of a sheet and then access this sheet based on this value.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, what you want is to copy the values of each rows of a sheet into their respective destination sheet which can be determined by the last column of each row.

I tried replicating the scenario on my end and came up with this code:

```
function myFunction(){
  let sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("test");
  let range = sheet.getRange(1,1,sheet.getLastRow(),sheet.getLastColumn())
  for(var i=1;i<=range.getLastRow();i++){
    let sourceval = sheet.getRange(i,1,1,range.getLastColumn());
    let destname = sheet.getRange(i,range.getLastColumn()).getValue();
    let destsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(destname);
    sourceval.copyTo(destsheet.getRange(destsheet.getLastRow()+1, 1));
  }  
}
```

**Snippet of sample spreadsheet**

[image]

This may not be the exact code that you are looking for. If you have questions, feel free to comment.